# Parsing JSON data in Android App error

Tags: java, android, json, instagram

In my Android app , i am trying to get popular media from instagram, i am using JSONParser class showed in this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {}

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
      // Making HTTP request
      try {
          // defaultHttpClient
          DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

          HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
          HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
          is = httpEntity.getContent();          
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
          }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
          }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

This is the the code i am trying to get to work:

```
private static  String urlInst = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id="+clientId;
public static  void Func() {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlInst);
    try {
    JSONArray pics = json.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < pics.length(); i++) { 
            JSONObject c=(JSONObject) pics.get(i);
            JSONObject user = c.getJSONObject("user");
            String name= user.getString("username");
            JSONObject img=c.getJSONObject("images");
            JSONObject thum=img.getJSONObject("thumbnail");
            String urlOfPic = thum.getString("url");                                  
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      } 
}
```

But I am getting error :

> Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> JSON Parser Error parsing data org.json.JSONEXception: End of input at character 0 of

I'm trying to figure out what is causing this error, any ideas? As far as I can see error is in this line.

> JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlInst);

But I am beginner so I am not sure. Help will be apreciated.

Full error log:

> 09-08 16:49:22.343: E/Buffer Error(9981): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-08 16:49:22.343: E/JSON Parser(9981): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hr.zadatak.undabot.instag/hr.zadatak.undabot.instag.StartShowing}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4668)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at hr.zadatak.undabot.instag.ListOfPhotos.LoadInstagramPictures(ListOfPhotos.java:51)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at hr.zadatak.undabot.instag.StartShowing.onCreate(StartShowing.java:16)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   09-08 16:49:22.351: E/AndroidRuntime(9981):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

Your error logs clearly show  what is going on

```
Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
```

That means that something in the `try` block was `null`.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
```

My guess is the `is` `InputStream`

```
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: how should i fix that ? do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that reader.readline() is returning null so 'sb' is not filled. Then the String 'json' is null and 'jObj' is also null and the problem emerges.
Please verify that reader.readline() is returning something different than null.

This happened to me when I was programming a feed reader (don't know why) but with this other way it works so you maybe want to try it:

Instead of:

```
try {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = null;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
     }
     is.close();
     json = sb.toString();
     ...
```

Try to do this way:

```
try {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = null;
     do {
        line = reader.readLine();
        if( line != null)
            sb.append(line + "\n");
     }while (line != null)
     is.close();
     json = sb.toString();
     ...
```

Answer (score -1):

First try change this code:

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
```

into this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String x = "";
    x = r.readLine();
    String total = "";

    while(x!= null){
    total += x;
    x = r.readLine();
    }

    json = total;
    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
```

and please add full error from logs.

Comment: Why do you think changing code as you propose will make a difference?

Comment: Because then we will know where can be a problem.

Comment: I should have asked how.

Comment: Right now I coppy code from page and everything works - I do not have this error. I will attach code below.

Comment: I added full error logs

and @daro2189 how everything works for you ? i still get the same error every time?

Comment: It worked when I'm using link from tutorial page but when I'm using yours link - there was an exception. I think try change link with https into link with http instead because string returned from this link is null